# How to find which [content] script execute the eval code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, content-script

Recently In my chrome, every page loads `https://s3.amazonaws.com/exthub/e/2/r/US_chrome.js?cached=true` and it is really annoying. I want to find which extension added such code snippets. But in the Network panel of Chrome devtools, the Initiator just shown `VM***`, I could not find which script invoke it even I set some break points in the scripts.

I have a lot of chrome extension, so it was difficult to check echo extension one by one. I also tried to search some keyword like `content_scripts`,`executeScript`,`amazonaws` and so on in `%AppData%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`, but I still could not find it.

Is there any convenient methods for finding the source script.

The `VM***` script is the following.

```js
(() => {
    if (document.querySelector('script[data-awssuidacr]') !== null) {
        return;
    }

    const head = document.querySelector('head');

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/exthub/e/2/r/US_chrome.js?cached=true';
    script.dataset['awssuidacr'] = 'KMyretRSNnBnMx4zVMxXIXOlCwtj9scH';

    head.appendChild(script);
})();
```

Comment: You could potentially use Notepad++ to search in the extensions directory for the key `KMyretRSNnBnMx4zVMxXIXOlCwtj9scH`

Comment: The file downloaded from AWS sets up a GA tracking with a custom dimension set to "YouTube Video Downloader". Maybe that helps to narrow down the responsible extension?

Comment: Devtools has a built-in multi-file search (Ctrl-Shift-F).

Answer (score 0):

@dorian Thanks for your advice. Now I tried to disable the "YouTube Video Downloader", and the scripts did not show up again.

I did not find the extension by searching some keywords was because I forgot the unpacked extension, they are not in the `%AppData%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` directory. And I go through the code and find the js code was `obfuscated`.

[image]